# $E_{\infty}$-algebras à la Lurie

Tags: homological-algebra, infinity-categories, operads

Let $D(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ be the derived category and derived infinity-category of cochain complexes of $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces.

If $A$ is a sheaf of cdgas over $\mathbb{F}_p$ on some site $C$, it seems that we may view $R\Gamma(C,A)$ as an $E_{\infty}$-algebra over $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{F}_p)$. I have not found a precise definition of this: the only definition of $E_{\infty}$-algebra that I know is algebra over an $E_{\infty}$-operad.

I would like to know whether the two notions are the same. For example, given an $E_{\infty}$-algebra in the $\infty$-sense, how to get an $E_{\infty}$-algebra in the classical sense? Do we get a functor between new and old $E_{\infty}$-algebras (fixing the operad)? Is it an equivalence?

Also, it seems that one can define Steenrod operations for these $E_{\infty}$-algebras in the $\infty$-sense. How does it go? Do they coincide with the old ones, via the functor above (if the functor exists...)

References would be much appreciated (I tried for a long time, without finding anything). If you are quoting from Lurie's book, could you please try to quote specific results as opposed to chapters?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but are you familiar with Segal's paper "Categories and Cohomology Theories"?  He defines Gamma spaces (certain spaces with a $\Gamma:= {\rm Fin}_*^{op}$ action).  In Appendix B he compares Gamma spaces with $E_\infty$ algebras.     Lurie's definition of $E_\infty$ algebra is in some sense based on Segal's Gamma spaces.  So the Appendix to Segal's paper could be a good warm-up to understanding the comparison between Lurie's model and operadic ones.

Comment: @PhilTosteson Thank you, I was not aware of that, I will take a look.

Comment: I think HA.4.5.4.7 is probably quickest to cite for what you're after (but the equivalence between $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-algebras in the infinity and non-infinity sense works in greater generality; one can use the Barr-Beck-Lurie theorem to prove it in many of your favorite examples). Steenrod operations and so on work the same- most of that stuff takes place in the homotopy category, not the model category/infinity category. (one needs to know that extended powers are what you think they are, and that is a special case of hocolims computing infty-categorical colims)

Comment: ah, theorem 7.10 here treats more general operads, for example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5675v2.pdf

Comment: Thank you @DylanWilson, this is very helpful. Do you know of a specific place where Steenrod operations are defined in the $\infty$-categorical sense? I only know it in the classical sense (e.g. May's paper 'An algebraic approach to Steenrod operations')

Comment: well there is this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.00054.pdf , the mod p case can also be dealt with along the same lines

Comment: but if you just want the *definition*, it is really the same, since the definition takes place in the homotopy category! (the extended power functor descends to a functor on the homotopy category, and that's all you ever use in the classical treatment; the thing I cited takes advantage of infty-categorical machinery to give some conceptual proofs of certain statements, like the Adem relations, but that's different)

Comment: other references include: Lurie's DAG XIII.2.2, Lurie's lecture notes on the Sullivan conjecture, and Nikolaus-Scholze IV.1.15